# How to access a array inside of a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

So, I am doing this short freecodecamp frontend project, where a random quote will generate and if you click "new quote" button, it will generate a random quote.
So I have declared this random quote outside the react component,

```
const randomQuotes = [{"quote": "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.", "author": "Kevin Kruse"},
{"quote": "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve.", "author": "Napoleon Hill"}]
```

And my react component is

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {   //this is just an example
      quote:'wow', 
      author:'wow2'
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({
      quote:'you clicked',
      author:'new one'
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div id="quote-box">
    <div id='text'>
      <h1 class='text-center'>{this.state.quote}</h1> //randomly generated quote will be shown here
    </div>
    <div id='author'>
      <h1 class='text-center'>{this.state.author}</h1>  //the author of the randomly generated quote will be shown here
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-4'>
        <button id="new-quote" class='btn btn-primary btn-block' onClick={this.handleClick}>New Quote</button>
           </div>
       <div class='col-xs-6'>
         <a id='tweet-quote' href='twitter.com/intent/tweet'>tweet</a>
      </div>
    
    </div>
   
  </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('quote-box'));
```

My question is, how to access the array which has been globally declared? should I create a new child component and pass this array as props? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can access it inside the first component by passing it as props, no need to create another child component. However you will need to map it to view all the data inside. Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: @CyberMessiah well there should be a quote when the page first reloads, and then there should be a random quote which will be generated from the array. what should I do?  I don't think I need map to show all the data.

Comment: I see. Then there should be logic to get a specific item from the array. For example you can put it in your handleClick function. You may use filter for this. https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-filter-filtering-arrays-in-react-with-examples will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

This array seems to be static so you can just export it like the following...

**randomQuotes.js**

```js
export const randomQuotes = [{"quote": "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.", "author": "Kevin Kruse"},
{"quote": "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve.", "author": "Napoleon Hill"}]
```

...and then import it in your component file:

**MyComponent.js**

```js
import { randomQuotes } from 'path/to/randomQuotes.js'

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
   ...
```